# Can I filter instances shown in admin changelist?

Tags: django, inheritance, admin

I have a model Child inheriting from a model Parent.
In the Parent admin I've got Parent and Child instances, while I would like to have only Parent instances (Child instances are managed in Child admin).

How can I do that?

thanks

jul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the `queryset` method in your ModelAdmin subclass to only return the objects you need.

```
class MyParentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

     def queryset(self, request):
         return Parent.objects.filter(whatever_your_criteria_is=True)
```